# Converting hash to CSV with Text::CSV::Slurp

Tags: perl, csv

I have a Perl hash that I need to write to JSON and to CSV formats.

A `print Dumper( \%formdata )` of my hash looks like this.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'SPRequest' => {
                              'xrelease' => '13038',
                              'macaddr' => '47:00:11:22:00:30',
                              'name' => 'localhost',
                              'description' => 'demo'
                            },
          '.submit' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
          'class' => 'SPRequest',
          '22406' => {
                       'win.profile' => 'production',
                       'win.os_version' => 'standard',
                       'win.os_part_size' => '1'
                     }
        };
```

Here is the snipplet of code I use to produce my json file.

```
my $form_data_file = "/tmp/${hostname}_${macaddr}.json";
open FH, ">$form_data_file" or die "Could not open $form_data_file. :$!\n";
print FH to_json( \%formdata, {pretty=>1} );
close FH;
```

I am able to output my JSON to a file which looks like this:

```
[red@tools-dev1 psong]$ cat /tmp/localhost_47-00-11-22-00-30.json 
{
   "SPRequest" : {
      "xrelease" : "13038",
      "macaddr" : "47:00:11:22:00:30",
      "name" : "localhost",
      "description" : "demo"
   },
   ".submit" : true,
   "class" : "SPRequest",
   "22406" : {
      "win.profile" : "production",
      "win.os_version" : "standard",
      "win.os_part_size" : "1"
   }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to create my CSV file:

```
my $form_data_file_csv = "/tmp/${hostname}_${macaddr}.csv";
# Text::CSV::Slurp wants arrayref of hashref
my $ARoHR = [ \%formdata ];
my $csv = Text::CSV::Slurp->create( input => $ARoHR);
open FH, ">$form_data_file_csv" or die "Could not open $form_data_file_csv. :$!\n";
print FH $csv;
close FH;
```

But the problem is my CSV file which ends up looking like this:

```
[red@tools-dev1 psong]$ cat /tmp/localhost_47-00-11-22-00-30.csv ; echo
.submit,22406,SPRequest,class
true,HASH(0x8d81918),HASH(0x8d67980),SPRequest
```

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: Looks like what I was doing wrong was expecting `Text::CSV::Slurp` to work with a Hash-of-Hash. So I rolled my own:

```
my @cols;
my @row;
sub hash2cvs {
        my $h = shift;
        my $p = shift || 'top';
        foreach my $k ( keys %{$h} ) {
                if (ref $h->{$k} eq ref {}) {
                        hash2cvs( $h->{$k}, $k );
                } else {
                        if ( $p eq 'top' ) {
                                push @cols, $k;
                        } else {
                                push @cols, "$p.$k";
                        }
                        push @row, $h->{$k};
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: `Data::Dumper` output is much easier to read if you pass it a reference, e.g. `print Dumper \%hash;` instead of `print Dumper %hash;`

Comment: fair enough. updated OP

Comment: If you want to map a nested data structure containing objects to a flat CSV file, you will have to decide how the mapping will work. For example, do you want your columns  named `SPRequest_xrelease`, `SPRequest_macaddr`, `SPRequest_name`, and so on? How should objects be stringified?

Comment: Geez I thought Text::CSV::Slurp would do that. What use is Text::CSV::Slurp then? I'll just roll my own then.

Comment: How could Text::CSV::Slurp possibly know how you want to map a data structure of arbitrary depth to a flat file? There's no standard for that; how would you express `{ foo => bar => [ 42, baz => { qux => 17 } ] }` as a CSV? The JSON spec includes arrays and objects, so [mapping between JSON and Perl data structures](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#MAPPING) is easier, although not without difficulties.

Comment: Well whatever software they use at http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm seems to be able to figure it out. I guess they are not using Perl or Text::CSV::Slurp.

Comment: That chokes on JSON like `{ "foo": [ "bar", "baz" ] }` and strips off two bits of information from `{ "foo": { "bar": { "baz": "qux" } } }`.

Comment: Ok great. thanks for you all help

Comment: @RedCricket: That site uses some custom JavaScript to create an arbitrary mapping of nested JSON data to CSV format. It is unreliable and far from being a standard, and you shouldn't expect any other software in any language to replicate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what I was doing wrong was, expecting `Text::CSV::Slurp` to work with a Hash-of-Hash. So I rolled my own:

```
my @cols;
my @row;
sub hash2cvs {
        my $h = shift;
        my $p = shift || 'top';
        foreach my $k ( keys %{$h} ) {
                if (ref $h->{$k} eq ref {}) {
                        hash2cvs( $h->{$k}, ($p eq 'top') ? $k : "$p.$k" );
                } else {
                        if ( $p eq 'top' ) {
                                push @cols, $k;
                        } else {
                                push @cols, "$p.$k";
                        }
                        push @row, $h->{$k};
                }
        }
}
```